# Javascript Questions: How does this code work?

Tags: javascript

Apologies for the vague question but I have been racking my brain as to why my code did not work for two hours and after the two hours I finally got it to work. Only I have no idea why it works now. Heres the scenario.

I have a "people" object that has person 1, person 2, and person 3, in it with various keys. I have a button that loops throught people object and places person1, person2, etc into a table "row". (person1,etc all have a radio button in the first "td" in their respective rows.)

I then click a button which checks if I selected one of the radio buttons mentioned above. Upon button press it loops through the object again primarily because I am using "document.getElementById" to identify the radio buttons. By looping through the people object I can the below:

```
for (var property in people) {
var radioButton = document.getElementById(property + "radio");
    if (radioButton.checked === true) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("macomCode", selectMacomField.value);
    sessionStorage.setItem("displayName", people[property].displayName);
    sessionStorage.setItem("dodId", people[property].edipi);
    sessionStorage.setItem("ptc", people[property].ptc);
    sessionStorage.setItem("email", people[property].email);
    sessionStorage.setItem("emailServiceClass", people[property].serviceClass);
    sessionStorage.setItem("mobileServiceClass", people[property].mobileServiceClass);
    sessionStorage.setItem("rms", people[property].rms);
    sessionStorage.setItem("journaling", people[property].journaled);
    window.open("depo/WilliamDepoPage.html",'_blank');//'width = 930, height = 700'*/
    break;
    }
}
```

Basically the above code loops through the people object checking if the radioButton was checked. It then stores the respective keys found in the people object into the SessionStorage and opens a window where the information will be populated. The break ensures that the code doesn't repeat after a match has been found.

The thing I noticed though with the above code is that it would only work when person1 was on the field. So if I just had person3 on the field it would throw an error of "cannot get id of null" (referring to the radioButton). Same goes for when I only had person2 on the field. But as long as person1 was on the field with person2 and person3 it worked perfectly.

After a bunch of tinkering i came up with this code:

```
for (var property in people) {
var radioButton = document.getElementById(property + "radio");
if (radioButton !== null) {
if (radioButton.checked === true) {
sessionStorage.setItem("macomCode", selectMacomField.value);
sessionStorage.setItem("displayName", people[property].displayName);
sessionStorage.setItem("dodId", people[property].edipi);
sessionStorage.setItem("ptc", people[property].ptc);
sessionStorage.setItem("email", people[property].email);
sessionStorage.setItem("emailServiceClass", people[property].serviceClass);
sessionStorage.setItem("mobileServiceClass", people[property].mobileServiceClass);
sessionStorage.setItem("rms", people[property].rms);
sessionStorage.setItem("journaling", people[property].journaled);
window.open("depo/WilliamDepoPage.html",'_blank');//'width = 930, height = 700'*/
break;
}
}
}
```

All I added was the:`if (radioButton !== null) {` and I can now pull up person3, and person2 by themselves and no error occurs. I understand that this checks if a radioButton is on the screen but I do not understand what roll it plays in the entire scheme of the above code. To me its saying if "radioButton" exists on the page execute the code. Well even before I input the `if(radioButton !== null)` the radioButton was already on the screen but an error was being thrown saying that radioButton was null.

Sorry for the long post but can anyone tell me what the `if(radioButton !== null)` does to make this code work? I'm glad it does, I'd just like to know why it works all of a sudden.

Appreciate the time and the assistance.

Comment: You just squelch your error. May be you need to investigate why actual radiobutton is absent.

Comment: Tips for improving this question: 1) work on a better title 2) properly indent your code to make it easier to read 3) provide a stack snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces the behavior (often, just by going through the trouble of creating a fiddle, you'll figure out the problem and be able to answer your question yourself).

Comment: The question is extremely broad, maybe narrow it down a little.

Comment: My guess is that `property` is not what you think it is, try adding `alert(property + "radio");` above `var radioButton = document.getElementById(property + "radio");` then see if it matches any id's on your page

Comment: If an Element is undefined it won't  have properties and an Error is consoled.

Comment: apologies for the vague question.  I'll keep that in mind for future questions. I tried the 'alert(property + "radio")' and it showed '"person1radio"' when running the for in loop. Im guessing the reason I am getting the error when person1 isn't on the field is because the 'document.getElementById(property + "radio")' only comes up as person1radio. By adding the 'if(radioButton !== null)' it checks if the radioButton with the appropriate name is on the screen if not it skips over and runs again until it finds an active radioButton? So if person1radio is not there go to person2 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't provide the HTML content. Let me guess, the list of radio button has following format:

```
<input ... id="1radio">
<input ... id="2radio">
<input ... id="3radio">
```

`for (var property in people)` mean `i=0...2`, we don't have radio for `id="0radio"`, right? :)

Hope that my answer may help you.